# Yeoman error when running yo webapp

Tags: yeoman

Running the latest of npm and node and I've checked to make sure their ownership privileges are correct, any ideas?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bold' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/util/common.js:5:56)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:101:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

Comment: This issue was resolved see https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/137.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Had the same issue. What solved it for me was manually updating yeoman-generator. For this I edited `package.json` in `/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/` and changed the version of `yeoman-generator` to `0.13.2` and ran `npm install` in the directory after that.

The git repository of generator-webapp is already using the latest yeoman-generator version but you have to wait for a new release I guess.

Comment: That's incorrect. The fix in the yeoman-generator was in a patch release, meaning you just need to clear the cache `npm cache clean` and reinstall `npm uninstall generator-webapp && npm install generator-webapp`. Recommended read: https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver/#ranges

Comment: You led me on the right path, thanks so much.  It seems just updating generator-webapp to 0.3.0 did the trick.  Seems like its being actively developed, so just pushing the individual package version forward sometimes does the trick.

Comment: Sindre Sorhus, you are even more correct. Sorry I didn't see your comment till just now.

Comment: yeoman has been updated since I wrote this. Shouldn't be a problem anymore.

Answer (score 4):

A few days ago a new version of node has been released, you need to update node and then update each package.

Update node

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
node -v
```

then update your packages

```
sudo npm update -g
cd myYoproject
npm update
```

Answer (score 1):

Your node package was not fully installed.

Try

```
npm update generator-webapp -g
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, the only thing I changed it was to update NodeJS to version 0.10.17, but I dunno...

Comment: you got the same version? maybe it's the update that is no more compatible with the current version of Yeoman (I've got the issue for every generator). it's a guess, I dunno frankly.